node's root directory is inside node_modules
I'm not sure I titled this correctly, as I'm not intimately familiar with node.
I've noticed two issues,
First, the @ alias isn't working as expected. I would think it should be set to the src directory. However, it appears to be set to a directory inside node_modules
Here is my direcotry structure:
project

dist
node_modules
public
src
.browserslistrc
.editorconfig
.eslintrc.js
babel.config.js
jsconfig.json
package-lock.json
package.json
vue.config.js


Second, my lsp can't find babel even though .eslintrc.js and bable.config.js are in the same directory. Here is my eslint file:
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    '@vue/airbnb',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'linebreak-style': 0,
  },
};

Here is the error I get:
Parsing error: No Babel config file detected for C:\Users\iamno\Projects\personal-site\src\App.vue. Either disable config file checking with requireConfigFile: false, or configure Babel so that it can find the config files.
If I change my .eslintrc.js file to this:
...
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    babelOptions: {
      configFile: '@/../../babel.config.js',
    },
  },
...

It can find babel now.
Here is my jsconfig.json file in case it helps:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  }
}

So the question is, why does node seem to think that some directory inside of node_modules is the root directory?
I've switching my jsconfig.json file to the following:
...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        __dirname + "/*"
      ]
    },
...

but it didn't yield any results.

@/../  does the same thing as without alias, src/../, so it's not an issue with alias.  Actual relative paths always start with ../ rather than have it elsewhere in the path.  You're actually making an absolute path, where ../ within it has unexpected behavior (or at least I can't explain it). Maybe someone else can explain technical reason why it goes into node_modules, but src/../../ will actually go up a directory from src.

What is "lsp"? " ne problem is eslint, another is ide autocomplete. If this occurs in IDE only then the problem is specific to IDE, the question doesn't mention this. "Here is the error I get:" - error where? If it's in ide then the problem could be specific to ide. Otherwise it's specific to project setup. @ doesn't make sense as path alias outside frontend project context, it's incorrect to use it in config files, it's recognized as non-existent npm package name. "'switching my jsconfig.json file" - json isn't js, you aren't supposed to use an expression with __dirname there.
